# How to fix "E: Unable to locate package rar" on current LTS release?

Tags: 16.04, rar

ubuntu version- 16.04 LTS 64bit

I am under the impression that is the optimal version to use?

Been searching on google but I cannot figure out this underlying issue while I am trying to install things, I have been able to get Spotify/Discord/Eclipse/Chrome but when I am trying to install 'rar' for unzipping .rar files I run into this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install rar
```

Returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rar
```

For everyone else apparently it should just download, not even sure how this apt-get works, I assume its connected to Ubuntu app store or something? I also updated the apt before I typed that.

Thanks, linux is great. Not sure why I didn't do this years ago. Just something I need to learn.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: @N0rbert I am on Version 16.04  LTS 64bit

Comment: My bias opinion is 16.04 is the absolute best to use and then 18.04 after most the bugs are ironed out say October 2018.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

1. Re-enable *multiverse* repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
   ```
2. Update package lists

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install `rar` for creating RAR-archives and `unrar` for extracting them:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install rar unrar
   ```

Comment: The "to install 'rar' for unzipping .rar files" part of the question suggest he is after the package `unrar` . `rar`  is in multiverse.

Comment: For `rar` and `unrar` you just need mulitverse, but the extra commands won't do anything if these repositories are enabled already. So I guess it is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not sure what multiverse is, but I have seen it a lot.